# Devise forms no longer clickable after new controller added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I had previously installed and configured `devise` and it worked fine. Forms worked fine. I then added a new `StaticPages` controller:

```
rails g controller StaticPages index landing about contribute
```

I set my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :cards

  root 'static_pages#index'
  get 'static_pages/landing' => 'static_pages#landing'
  get 'static_pages/about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'static_pages/contribute' => 'static_pages#contribute'

  unauthenticated do
    root to: 'static_pages#landing', :as => 'unauthenticated'
  end

end
```

After this the `users/sign_in` page for `devise` rendered, but the forms were not clickable. I click on them and they do not highlight nor allow text to be entered. I can however `tab` through the form to enter credentials and press `enter` to sign in. **Why do the forms no longer work?**

Here is the sign in form:

```
<body id="sign-in">
  <div class="wrapper-center">
    <div class="container-form">
      <div class="container-fields">
        <h2 class="light-text">Sign in</h2>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password" %>
          </div>

          <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
            <div class="field remember-me">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox-label">
                <%= f.label :remember_me %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end -%>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="devise-links">
      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further code, it's difficult to diagnose, however, this *may* have something to do with it:

```
<body id="sign-in">
```

Why are you including a `<body>` tag in your `views`?

When you have a Rails app, you have two "levels" of views - the *layout* and the *view*.

The *layout* is the wrapper for the whole page; is where you'd put `<body>` tags. The *view* is the specific code for that particular page.

Thus, I'd expect to see something like the following:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
....
<body>
  <%= yield %>

#app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
<div class="container-form">
  <div class="container-fields">
    <%= form_for ... %>
```

Again, I can only presume you've included `<body>` in your view. I don't have any other reference.

--

The idea that you have an HTML issue would be congruent with your issue actually - it's the *interaction* with your form which is an issue, not the submission.

If you had a problem with Rails, you'd not be able to sign in. Therefore, it's *likely* an issue with the way the form is rendered, which is HTML & CSS.

---

As an aside, you should also look up about adding [non-restful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (for your `static pages`):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static_pages, only: :index do
   %i(landing about contribute).each do |option|
      get :option, on: :collection
   end
end
```

*Another* suggestion would be to keep those "static" pages in your *application* controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
%w(landing about contribute).each do |option|
   get option, to: "application##{option}"
end
```

... you'd back that up with the respective methods in your `ApplicationController`:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def landing
     ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. This is good stuff. I ended up going back through my commit history and realized that the was a `z-index` on the `fields-container` `div` that was causing the issue.